# Basic Category Theory question.

Tags: category-theory, adjoint-functors, functors

This question should be very basic, which jibes with  the fact that I continue to be a beginner in this subject.  Here goes:  If a functor is  not full, or  not faithful, can it have a left (or right) adjoint that is full or faithful.

For context, *full* and *faithful* describe functors for which the corresponding maps of morphisms are surjective and injective respectively.

It looks like this question might be quite [similar](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/957991/403337).

This question occurred to me when thinking about the group of units functor and its left adjoint, the group ring functor, with $\mathbb Z$ as the ring, over [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4146128/403337).

Looking at this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/959017/403337), it seems the answer is quite straight forward when one of the functors is full *and* faithful, since then we have an isomorphism of Homs.

Update: that last bit turned out to be false.   However,  I noticed while reading that if we further require our functor $F:\mathcal C\to\mathcal D $ be *essentially surjective*, we get an *equivalence of categories*.  These notions are about what one would expect,  but I won't define them here.

Comment: For one part of the question, the inclusion of abelian groups into groups is full and faithful, but its left adjoint (the abelianization functor) is not faithful.

Comment: Thanks @DanielSchepler  That was easy.  Nice example.

Comment: If $G,H$ are abelian groups and $\phi : G \to H$ is a morphism of groups, then the underlying set map $|G| \to |H|$ also induces a morphism of abelian groups.

Comment: It appears to be a subtle point,  but since the functor is the inclusion,  fullness follows easily from the fact that we only need to look at morphisms of groups that are in fact abelian. @DanielSchepler correct me

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An algebraic example was given in the comments, so here's a topological counterexample.

The forgetful functor $U$ from the category $\mathcal{Top}$ of topological spaces and continuous maps to the category $\mathcal{Set}$ of sets has a left adjoint $D$ which takes a set to the discrete space on that set.

$D$ is fully faithful, since a continuous map between discrete spaces is the same as a function between the underlying sets. More formally, given two sets $X$ and $Y$, every map between $D(X)$ and $D(Y)$ is equal to $D(f)$ for a unique function $f \colon X \to Y$.

However, $U$ is not fully faithful. Given topological spaces $X$ and $Y$, there are (in general) far fewer continuous functions between $X$ and $Y$ than there are functions between $U(X)$ and $U(Y)$.

Comment: Still working through some of this.   But I like your answer.

Comment: Just as a note, $U$ actually is faithful, but fails to be fully faithful because it's not full.